# Erro ao buscar por CNPJ Spring Boot

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Estou tentando localizar uma empresa pelo CNPJ dela em um DB (H2), mas está retornando erro

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-03-30T19:30:23.823+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/empresas/cnpj/30101554000146"
}
```

Já tentei outras alternativas usando: `http://localhost:8080/fornecedores/cnpj/'30.101.554/0001-46`', `http://localhost:8080/fornecedores/cnpj/"30.101.554/0001-46"`, mas o erro persiste.

Está assim a implementação:

```
lang-jsp
@Entity
@Table(name = "empresa")
public class Empresa implements Serializable {
    
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    private String nome;
    @CNPJ
    private String cnpj;
    
    //skipped
}

public interface EmpresaRepositorio extends JpaRepository<Empresa,Long> {
    
     Optional<Empresa> findByCnpj(String cnpj);

}

public class EmpresaDTO {

    private Long id;

    private String nome;

    private String cnpj;
    
    //skipped   
}

@Service
@Transactional
public class EmpresaServico {

    @Autowired
    private EmpresaRepositorio empresaRepositorio;
    
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public EmpresaDTO buscarPeloId(Long id) {
        Empresa resultado = empresaRepositorio.findById(id).get();
        EmpresaDTO dto = new EmpresaDTO(resultado);
        return dto;
    }   
    
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public EmpresaDTO buscarPeloCnpj(String cnpf) {
        Optional<Empresa> resultado = empresaRepositorio.findByCnpj(cnpf);
        EmpresaDTO dto = new EmpresaDTO(resultado.get());
        return dto;
        
    }
    
}


@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/empresas")
public class EmpresaControle {
    
    @Autowired
    private EmpresaServico empresaServico;
    
    
    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public EmpresaDTO buscarPeloId(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return empresaServico.buscarPeloId(id);
    }
    
    @GetMapping(value = "/cnpj/{cnpj}")
    public EmpresaDTO buscarPeloCnpj(@PathVariable String cnpj) {
        return empresaServico.buscarPeloCnpj(cnpj);
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Modifiquei @GetMapping(value = "/cnpj/{cnpj}"):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/empresas")
public class EmpresaControle {
    
    @Autowired
    private EmpresaServico empresaServico;
    
    
    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public EmpresaDTO buscarPeloId(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return empresaServico.buscarPeloId(id);
    }
    
    @GetMapping(value = "/cnpj/**")
    public EmpresaDTO buscarPeloCnpj(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return empresaServico.buscarPeloCnpj(request.getRequestURI().split(request.getContextPath() + "/cnpj/")[1]);
    }
    
}
```

[Aqui foi a referência usada para a modificação](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-slash-character-in-url)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
Recomendo usar 

@GetMapping(value = "/cnpj/{cnpj}")
    public EmpresaDTO buscarPeloCnpj(@PathVariable String cnpj) {
        return empresaServico.buscarPeloCnpj(cnpj);
    }
```

Comment: Era como eu estava fazendo, mas por ter "/" do CNPJ na URL acabava dando erro 404